# Is there way to acces every RecyclerViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I have a recyclerview with data that changes during the lifecycle of an app, lets say that in my recycler view holders i have an edittext field that comes with populated data but I want user to have access to change that data, is there a way that when the button is pressed i can somehow access all of those textfields at once?

Comment: How do you mean, "access them"? What do you want to do to them? Generally you display your current data and set up listeners etc during ``onBindViewHolder`` - if your underlying data changes you call something like ``notifyDataSetChanged`` and the ``RecyclerView`` will call ``onBindViewHolder`` again for the relevant items to update them

Comment: by cleating an interface you can easily do this...

Comment: This won't work because there are only as many EditTexts as are visible on the screen at a time. When a new one scrolls on screen, it is a recycled view from one that just scrolled off screen. You need a listener on the EditText that stores the value somewhere else as it changes. You need that anyway to use when binding the views that scroll off and back onto the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm you could keep 2 parallel lists in your recycle view adapter? one that has the main data, the other one is updated whenever the user changes something on an edit text.

Once the user presses the update button, you can just copy the data from list2(with modified data) to list1 (original) and update the recycler view.

for example

inside onBindviewholder()

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // find your edittext to set a listener for text change
       // get the current item from list2 (list2 has same item originally as the original list)
keep updated the list2 data here.

       
    }
```

on the main activity once the user presses the button you can do

```
adapter.mainList = new ArrayList<>(adapter.list2)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```